# Retrieving list values from my hashmap returns null

Tags: java, list, dictionary

My outer map contains string as key and values as an `ArrayList` which in turn holds an inner map of keys and values as strings. When I try to put the data into list and map and iterate through the outer map, it works fine. But when I try to retrieve a specific list value for a given key, it returns `null`.

What am I doing wrong? My outer map structure is:

```
 Map<String,List<HashMap<String,String>>>
    Myclass{

        private static void method1{
        //Other code reading my file            
            while (((lineReader = bReader.readLine()) != null)
                    && (lineReader.length() > 0)) {
                innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                textData = lineReader.split("\t");
                firstColm = textData[0];
                innerMap .put("secondColm", textData[1]);
                innerMap .put("thirdColm", textData[2]);

                if (outerMap.containsKey(firstColm)) {
                    MyList = (List) outerMap.get(firstColm);
                } else {
                    MyList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                    outerMap.put(firstColm,MyList );

                }
                MyList.add(innerMap );
            }
                      }
        public static List<Map<String, String>> getDetails(String key) {
            return outerMap.get(key);
        }
    }
        Myclass2
        { 
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            List<Map<String, String>> Mylist = Myclass.getDetails("1");
            System.out.println("User Data :"+ Mylist);      
        } }
```

I perform this to read a text file and store it in `innermap`, group it as a list and use the list as values for storing it with another key.

```
 getDetails("1") 1 -> specifies the key of the outer map.
```

Comment: Please add the code for `Myclass.getDetails("1")`.

Comment: Is that the exact code of the main method that you're running when you get the null value?  If so, I would expect outerMap to be empty when you try to print userData.

Comment: But, the outer map isnt empty.. When I iterate my outer map in method1, my outer map data is getting displayed.

Comment: In this case, the code adding elements to the map is broken. Does any other key work? If not, add `System.out.println` when you put new items into the map so you can see which keys it uses.

Comment: No..Tries with all possible keys from my text file. No key works.

Comment: Please show us the line where you put values into the map (i.e. where you call `put()` and the types of the arguments (the lines where you declare them).

Comment: Kindly check the updated question. have added it.

Comment: `Map<String,List<HashMap<String,String>>>` :-O Have you considered wrapping some part of that in a class? Might make debugging easier.

Comment: Add `System.out.println("["+firstColm+"]")` after `firstColm = textData[0];` and check what this prints.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to be this line:

```
firstColm = textData[0];
```

Possible causes:

- There is a `\t` before the first column
- There is other white space before the first `\t` in the line. `" 1 "` doesn't equal `"1"`

To debug this, add

```
System.out.println("["+firstColm+"]")
```

after the line above to see what keys you really have.